# flatsome sidebar slide out navigation

Tags: slide, submenu

I have my new website almost done locally and it is ready to upload. I'm using the Flatsome theme.
I only run into something I really need to change

I have a lot of categories and subcategories for my webshop.
Flatsome automaticly creates dropdown submenus but since I have a lot of sub categories per categorie my sidebar gets really long!  I really need to have my sidebar as the mobile version of flatsome but without the "hamburger" icon.

The sidebar of the mobile version has no dropdown but slides the submenus into a new sidebar.
Can this be done for the desktop version and if so.. how can I do this?

I have tried to edit my css code but that did not work

```
`.off-canvas .mobile-sidebar-slide {
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}

.off-canvas .mobile-sidebar-slide .sidebar-menu {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform .3s;
    will-change: transform
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-1 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu,.mobile-sidebar-levels-1 .nav-slide>li>ul.children {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transform: none;
    width: 100%
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-1 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li,.mobile-sidebar-levels-1 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-1 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu.is-current-slide,.mobile-sidebar-levels-1 .nav-slide>li>ul.children.is-current-slide {
    display: block
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-1 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu.is-current-parent,.mobile-sidebar-levels-1 .nav-slide>li>ul.children.is-current-parent {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-right: 100%;
    width: 200%
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header),.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header) {
    border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    transition: background-color .3s
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>a,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>a {
    color: hsla(0,0%,40%,.85);
    font-size: .8em;
    letter-spacing: .02em;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header).active,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header):hover,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header).active,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header):hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05)
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>.sub-menu,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>ul.children,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>.sub-menu,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>ul.children {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 200%;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transform: none;
    width: 100%
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>.sub-menu>li,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>ul.children>li,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>.sub-menu>li,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>ul.children>li {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>.sub-menu.is-current-slide,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>ul.children.is-current-slide,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>.sub-menu.is-current-slide,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>ul.children.is-current-slide {
    display: block
}

.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>.sub-menu.is-current-parent,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>.sub-menu>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>ul.children.is-current-parent,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>.sub-menu.is-current-parent,.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav-slide>li>ul.children>li:not(.nav-slide-header)>ul.children.is-current-parent {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-right: 100%;
    width: 200%
}

.nav-slide {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-top: 20px
}

.nav-slide .active>.toggle {
    transform: none
}

.nav-slide>li {
    flex-shrink: 0
}

.nav-slide-header .toggle {
    margin-left: 0!important;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative!important;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0!important;
    width: 100%
}


`
```

is there anyone who can help me?

I edited the above code but this only effects the off canvas and does not change my "normal" sidebar to the slide menu like the off canvas.